# Need clarifications working with Views in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, cs193p, cgcontextref

Ok, I'm learning programming for iOS with Stanford's online course on iTunes U (CS193P) but I can't exactly get a hold on how all the stuff from UIView works.

Could someone explain how the following things work cohesively and how I should use them?

CGContextRef
CGContext(if they're not the same thing)
drawRect
awakeFromNib

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't really a good question for SO. Please read the FAQ. You're asking for a general explanation of four different concepts. SO questions should be about single, specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGContextRef
```

is just the reference to

`CGContext`.

```
drawRect
```

makes your view to draw (or redraw) itself at selected rect. [Read here.](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/DrawRect) 
I never used it by myself, for me it was enough to do all work in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidLoad:`.

**After all outlets and actions are connected, the nib loader sends awakeFromNib to every object in the nib.** (c) [Read about it here.](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AwakeFromNib)